# Can I increase the level from my USB microphone?

Tags: audio, usb, microphone

I have this usb headset: http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/audio-478

With the level turned all the way up in System Preferences, it's not loud enough for some uses.

Is there a way to increase this level?

10.10.3

2014 15" Retina

Comment: on what hardware and what operating system

Comment: @Buscar웃 I added the info to my question

Answer (score 1):

You may use volume booster software like

## [Boom](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boom/id415312377?mt=12)

Or

In iTunes Library select media with low volume and press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> . Go to Options and make Volume Adjustments.

Or

VLC allow you to increase volume to 200% by simply scrolling all the way up.

Comment: those are for output not for input as asked.

Comment: Ops, didn't notice the microphone at the end of question.